# Kaleido chainid when connecting Metamask

Tags: metamask, kaleido

In Kaleido docs (https://docs.kaleido.io/developers/smart-contracts/metamask/), it is stated that chainID is optional but this is misleading. Metamask does not allow user to save without chainid.

Comment: Can you fix the format of this question, by removing the answer from the question body and make an answer instead? that way will be easier for others to know this wuestion has the solution on it

Answer (score 1):

The Kaleido documentation has been updated to reflect chainID as a required parameter.  You can easily find the chainID for your Kaleido environment by clicking on the environmental "Settings" tab in the lefthand navigation of the Kaleido console.  The chainID is displayed in the upper right corner of the "Settings" page.

Additionally, when creating your custom connection to Kaleido you have the option to input a symbol for your token smart contract (the address will be automatically derived).  If you skip this step (which is entirely optional), you can use the "Import Token" option within MetaMask and you simply need to provide the address of the relevant token smart contract(s).

Comment: this should be the official answer imo, sorry i can't upvote answers yet

Answer (score 0):

had some trouble with this so leaving here for others - To get around this, try a random chainid (eg.1234). After auth prompt, you will get an error message telling you what the chain id should be. Replace and save. NOTE this was before @Nick Gaski's answer

Comment: please look at @Nick Gaski's answer